# Не подключается css к html, помогите пожалуйста

Tags: html, css, html5, sublime-text, link

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверила всё несколько раз. Написано всё правильно но css не подключается(((

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0):

попробуй убрать type="text/css"

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему у вас файл html находится в папке css, тогда в href просто укажите style.css

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте местами элементы в теге `link`.
Правильный вариант:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```